# Creating a Gradle build for Android project that uses ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, viewpagerindicator

When I run `gradle AssembleDebug` I get an error saying support-v4 is already added. I can't figure out why it's being added twice. The full project structure and error log is given below.

My directory structure is as follows (Removed extra directories for clarity).

```
├── settings.gradle
├── project
│   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── res
│   └── src
└── vpi
    ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── res
    └── src
```

settings.gradle contains

```
include 'project'
include 'vpi'
```

project/build.gradle contains

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
  compile project(':vpi')
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 18
  buildToolsVersion "18.1"

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

      // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
      // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
      // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
      // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
      // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
      // by a similar customization.
      debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
      release.setRoot('build-types/release')
  }
}
```

vpi/build.gradle contains

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 18
  buildToolsVersion "18.1"

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the command `gradle AssembleDebug` I get this output.

```
:project:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:project:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:project:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:compileLint
:vpi:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:prepareReleaseDependencies
:vpi:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:compileRelease
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:vpi:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:vpi:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:project:prepareAndroidAppVpiUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:project:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:project:prepareDebugDependencies
:project:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:project:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:project:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:project:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:project:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:project:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:project:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:project:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:project:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:project:dexDebug

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
1 error; aborting
:project:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project:dexDebug'.
> Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/18.1.0/dx --dex --output /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/build/libs/project-debug.dex /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/build/classes/debug /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/build/dependency-cache/debug /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/build/exploded-bundles/AndroidAppVpiUnspecified.aar/libs/android-support-v4.jar /Users/yasith/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2/jar/d7e275ba05aa380ca254f72d0c0ffebaedc3adcf/jsoup-1.7.2.jar /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/build/exploded-bundles/AndroidAppVpiUnspecified.aar/classes.jar /Users/yasith/Projects/Mississauga-Busses/AndroidApp/project/build/exploded-bundles/ComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440.aar/classes.jar /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/18.0.0/support-v4-18.0.0.jar
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
    1 error; aborting


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 25.296 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my project/build.gradle file to look like this. (Removed the `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'` bit).

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':vpi')
  compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

This seems to make `gradle DebugAssemble` work. I did run `gradle clean DebugAssemble` too, not sure if that had anything to do with this working.

Also had to add a `local.properties` file to the project root which contained.

```
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```

After doing this, importing the settings.gradle file from Android Studio worked.